# Difference between 'imagecopy()' and 'imagecopymerge()'?

Tags: php, gd

What is the difference between these 2 functions from the PHP GD library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These two functions are both quite similar in that they copy one picture into another.

The way these functions differ is in the last parameter: `imagecopy()` always overwrites all the pixels in the destination with those of the source, whereas `imagecopymerge()` merges the destination pixels with the source pixels by the amount specified in the extra parameter:

```
0 means "keep the source picture fully", 
100 means "overwrite with the source picture fully", 
and 50 means "mix the source and destination pixel colours equally".
```

The `imagecopy()` function is therefore equivalent to calling `imagecopymerge()` and passing in 100 as the last parameter.

Comment: That's quite interesting, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the [last parameter, `$pct`](http://php.net/imagecopymerge):

> **`pct`**
>
> The two images will be merged according to pct which can range from 0
>   to 100. When pct = 0, no action is taken, when 100 this function
>   behaves identically to imagecopy() for pallete images, while it
>   implements alpha transparency for true colour images.

It's about *transparently blending* two images together vs. just copy-pasting over.

Answer (score 1):

[imagecopymerge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) look **pct** arg description

> The two images will be merged according to pct which can range from 0
>   to 100. When pct = 0, no action is taken, when 100 this function
>   behaves identically to imagecopy() for pallete images, except for
>   ignoring alpha components, while it implements alpha transparency for
>   true colour images.